# Can I do bufferflow attack on my iOS application (under test), on iphone 5 which is not jail broken ?

Tags: ios, iphone-5, buffer-overflow, security-testing

I need to find vulnerabilities related to buffer over flow in my iOS app. I have basic understanding of what buffer over flow is, but I don't know about any tools/techniques to find bugs in my iOS application related to bufferoverflow.

Can anyone help?

Regards

Novice

Comment: Try profiling your app with Instruments tools. On Xcode, go to `Product->Profile` and select appropriate tool for testing, and run the app from there. For the issues with memory use `Leaks` tool which will detect memory leaks for you. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Fahri. Could you please elaborate **"profiling your app with Instruments tools"**. 
Also if you could name any appropriate tool for buffer overflow test it would be very helpful.

Comment: Also I don't have any source code available of this app. I just have this iOS
app installed in my iPhone 5. And I need to do buffer overflow testing on this non-jail broken device. Is it possible?? I am feeling completely trapped 
now .. :-(